# When $x=0$ implies $x=1$?

Tags: logic

Can somebody please help me.
I have to do a logic question The question is 
$x=0$ implies $x=1$. I think the answer is for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ except $x=0$. Can you guys tell me if I am correct?

Comment: That's not a question, it's just a statement.  What's the question?

Comment: If the question is "for which $x\in \mathbb R $ the formula $P(x)$ is true, then yes, it's true for all $x\not = 0$. Try to make the truth table of that formula.

Comment: "$x=0 \rightarrow x=1$" is equivalent to "$x \neq 0 \mbox{ or } x=1$". I think that from here you will be able to understand why the values satisfying this are $\{ x:x \neq 0\}$

Comment: @littleO The question is “Can you guys tell me if i am correct”.

Comment: @MJD Well, I was confused by the line, "The question is $x = 0$ implies $x = 1$," because "$x = 0$ implies $x = 1$" isn't a question.  I think it would be helpful to have a more clear statement of the question.

Comment: Why is this upvoted? It is an impressively unclear question...

Answer (score 2):

Only when $x\ne 0$ because the antecedent is false.